# WP Bakery Load More Button loads the same posts

Tags: posts, blog, read-more, recent-posts

I'm trying to feed posts in my blog page with a WP bakery widget. I have 8 posts published, but when I hit load more button it loads first 3 posts instead of those in the end. Attaching screenshots, also I'm not sure what else info do I need to share, so please tell me if some additional details needed.[image: blog settings]

Comment: THats an error form console "isotope not initialized. Cannot call methods, i.e. $().isotope("layout")"